# How to get the up time of the machine?

Tags: .net

I would like to display the up time of the machine my code is running, how can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the command line : **net statistics workstation** and parse the output. The time that machine is running is after "Statistics since ".

Comment: If you want to retrieve this from .net this is a bad approach.  You are relying on "net" from having the same format output in the future, and that it will be available and included on all machines.

Comment: Command line output can also vary from one OS version to another, which can make it fail after deployment.  I had this happen from XP to Vista, and the only difference was an extra carriage return in one OS vs the other.

Comment: If the Workstation is restarted, this will (I believe) give an incorrect value

Comment: I meant the Workstation service

Comment: This is a terrible solution and should not be the accepted answer. 1) Command-line output may vary between OS. 2) It only tells you when the Workstation service was last started/restarted. 3) The workstation service is not guaranteed to even be running at all. 4) Doesn't work on unix, even with samba installed.

Answer (score 9):

Try this link. It uses the **System.Environment.TickCount** property

> Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started. - MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(VS.80).aspx

Note: this method will work for 25 days because TickCount is an Int32.

Comment: Consequently, if the system runs continuously, TickCount will increment from zero to Int32.MaxValue for approximately 24.9 days, then jump to Int32.MinValue, which is a negative number, then increment back to zero during the next 24.9 days. How can I know if it runs more than 25 days???

Comment: I guess Microsoft never expected a machine to stay up for more than 25 days.

Comment: Would a MS OS even run after not restarting that long? haha

Comment: I know a guy with WinXP who's had his laptop running for the better part of a year, so yeah, it would :P

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Management;
using System.Linq;

TimeSpan GetUptime()
 { var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT LastBootUpTime 
                                 FROM Win32_OperatingSystem 
                                 WHERE Primary='true'");
   var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
   var str = mos.Get().First().Properties["LastBootUpTime"].Value.ToString();

   return DateTime.Now - ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(str);
 }
```

(Based on code from http://bytes.com/forum/thread502885.html)

Answer (score 4):

Curious that none of them considered Stopwatch yet?

Precise and bigger than `System.Environment.TickCount`, not involving OS horrific perf counters, WMI or native calls, and well really simple:

```
var ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
var uptime = ((double)ticks) / Stopwatch.Frequency;
var uptimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Diagnostics

```
using System.Diagnostics;
..........
PerformanceCounter perfc = new PerformanceCounter("System","System Up Time");
perfc.NextValue();
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(perfc.NextValue());
..........
```

Comment: Doesn't show me the real time. Should be 25h30min and it display 15hours18mins

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and proper way to do this is

```
public static TimeSpan GetUptime()
{
    ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(@"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem=@");
    DateTime lastBootUp = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["LastBootUpTime"].ToString());
    return DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - lastBootUp.ToUniversalTime();
}
```

Comment: This returns an exception with the message:`Invalid object path` on Windows 2003 Server running in a web service in IIS6

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, on *nix, use uptime(1)

Comment: There must be a C (3) call, right?  What API does uptime(1) call to get this information?

Comment: Well, on Linux, GNU coreutils just reads /proc/uptime, Read the full sources at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/uptime.c

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reference; in the Win32 world, you can use:

[GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx), [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724411(VS.85).aspx), or [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

There's many definitions of what up could mean.  Assuming we are talking about an application, then a remote ping of a simple service might suffice.  [Keynote](http://www.keynote.com/) provide enterprise level solutions for the web and there must be many others out, many free i would imagine.

UPDATE: given this was tagged .net I assumed we are interested in the uptime of an application.  Is it an application within which you want to show uptime of the machine.