# Retrieve system uptime using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uptime

Is there a simple way to get a system's uptime using C#?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265089/how-to-get-the-up-time-of-the-machine/265101#265101

Comment: I just wanted to say that the uptime nowadays might appear much longer, since systems no longer shut down but hibernate instead (Windows 10)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
public TimeSpan UpTime {
    get {
        using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time")) {
            uptime.NextValue();       //Call this an extra time before reading its value
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first call to uptime.NextValue will return 0.

Comment: What if counter name is localized?

Comment: Get localised names (2 = System, 674 = System Up Time) using:

    `StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
    uint buf_size = (uint)buffer.Capacity;
    Win32.PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex(null, id, buffer, ref buf_size);
    return buffer.ToString();`

Comment: I object that this is 'a simple way'. On top of it, try run it on *nix.

Comment: @Rbjz usually qualifying an answer with "using C#" means the OP is not looking for an answer that requires anything not already present in the .NET Framework. As of 2009 this was the simplest C# method for acquiring a non-overflowing "uptime" -- alternatives included querying WMI and scanning the System Event Log for a boot record.. and by comparison this method is the "simplest" and would work over all versions of Windows supported by .NET 

Not "using C#" requires PInvoke; `GetTickCount64` (not in all Windows vers) or `ZwQuerySystemInformation` (undoc), or `sysinfo` (on posix+SVR4 systems)

Comment: This function does not return the Uptime, it returns the duration between last restart and now. Turning the computer on and of does not affect this behaviour.

Answer (score 52):

I'm a bit late, but another *simple* way is to use the [GetTickCount64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which is available starting with Windows Vista and does not overflow as GetTickCount does:

```
public static TimeSpan GetUpTime()
{
    return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(GetTickCount64());
}

[DllImport("kernel32")]
extern static UInt64 GetTickCount64();
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you much for posting this :)

Comment: GetTickCount64() returns error "the System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point".

Comment: @Goby Windows Vista or later? Typo? Renamed “GetTickCount64” to something else?

Comment: `GetTickCount64 ... does not overflow` - It will overflow when they find a way to make my code run for 585 billion years

Comment: @rkagerer, wait and see. Short sighted assumptions like those took us to y2k and end of epoch time 2038 =D

Comment: @Rbjz y2k wasn't nearly as eventful as it is made out to be, just as well these APIs aren't built on "assumptions" they are built on "hardware limits"; `GetTickCount` is a performance API calculated from kernel structures that were 32bit at the time, `GetTickCount64` surfaced after those kernel structures supported 64bit values.

Might be worth noting that `GetTickCount` was originally meant to provide time correlation between system performance counters over a short period, a use which was later superceded by `QueryPerformanceCounter` for higher resolution correlation over a longer period.

Comment: No need to use P/Invoke for this in the most recent .NET versions, as the **Environment** class now has a [`TickCount64` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount64?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @StevenRands Would you like to post a new answer with `Environment.TickCount64`? I think this is now the "best" solution.

Answer (score 30):

[System.Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) gets the number of milliseconds since the system was restarted.

Beware though that it is an Int32 and will overflow after 24.9 days and will become negative. See the remarks on the MDSN docs.

Comment: To be pedantic, convert that property to milliseconds with TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond.aspx)

Comment: Or, better yet, call TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds

Comment: @SlLaks - am I missing something?  You've got to get milliseconds from ticks before you can get a TimeSpan from milliseconds.

Comment: @SLaks - or maybe you mean TimeSpan.FromTicks().

Comment: Confusingly, Environment.TickCount returns a number of milliseconds, not .Net ticks (A .Net tick is 100 nanoseconds).

Comment: To get ~49.7 days worth of continuity from it, just cast it to a `UInt32`/`uint`.

Comment: Isn't this a faster and better answer if you really just want uptime?

Comment: In the most recent .NET versions the **Environment** class has a [`TickCount64` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount64?view=net-5.0), which avoids the wrap-around issue.

Comment: Cannot be recommended to anyone serious due to the overflow. Please don't use it.

Answer (score 25):

My machine has an uptime of `58 days 17 hours` according to Task Manager. I went through and tried each answer here and the fast ones are off by a little bit (~1-3 minutes roughly, but over 58 days of uptime):

```
Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp():                   58days 17hours 11minutes 25seconds
~Time to calculate (ms): 6.8413
DllImport GetTickCount64():                 58days 17hours 13minutes 34seconds
~Time to calculate (ms): 0.2192
PerformanceCounter(System, System Up Time): 58days 17hours 14minutes 02seconds
~Time to calculate (ms): 1233.2854
ManagementObject LastBootUpTime:            58days 17hours 14minutes 02seconds
~Time to calculate (ms): 30.0283
```

The last two, using PerformanceCounter or using ManagementObject, are always within the same second as Windows Task Manager (just have to take my word for it, or try it yourself with the code below). Based on the results I am going to use the `ManagementObject LastBootUpTime` method because it's drastically faster than the `PerformanceCounter` but is still perfectly accurate when compared to Task Manager.

Note that I did subtract the current elapsed time from each method before printing the times, but the whole thing takes less than 2 seconds to run so the time shift can't be explained by improperly accounting for execution time anyway. Here's the code I used:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32")]
extern static UInt64 GetTickCount64();

public static void Main()
{
    var start = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var eachStart = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    var uptime = ((double)ticks) / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    var uptimeTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime);
    Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch.GetTimeStamp():                   " + uptimeTimeSpan.Subtract(start.Elapsed).ToString(@"dd\d\a\y\s\ hh\h\o\u\r\s\ mm\m\i\n\u\t\e\s\ ss\s\e\c\o\n\d\s"));
    Console.WriteLine($"~Time to calculate (ms): {eachStart.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}");

    eachStart.Restart();
    Console.WriteLine("DllImport GetTickCount64():                 " + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(GetTickCount64()).Subtract(start.Elapsed).ToString(@"dd\d\a\y\s\ hh\h\o\u\r\s\ mm\m\i\n\u\t\e\s\ ss\s\e\c\o\n\d\s"));
    Console.WriteLine($"~Time to calculate (ms): {eachStart.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}");

    eachStart.Restart();
    var upTime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
    upTime.NextValue();       //Call this an extra time before reading its value
    Console.WriteLine("PerformanceCounter(System, System Up Time): " + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(upTime.NextValue()).Subtract(start.Elapsed).ToString(@"dd\d\a\y\s\ hh\h\o\u\r\s\ mm\m\i\n\u\t\e\s\ ss\s\e\c\o\n\d\s"));
    Console.WriteLine($"~Time to calculate (ms): {eachStart.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}");

    eachStart.Restart();
    ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(@"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem=@");
    DateTime lastBootUp = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["LastBootUpTime"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("ManagementObject LastBootUpTime:            " + (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - lastBootUp.ToUniversalTime()).Subtract(start.Elapsed).ToString(@"dd\d\a\y\s\ hh\h\o\u\r\s\ mm\m\i\n\u\t\e\s\ ss\s\e\c\o\n\d\s"));
    Console.WriteLine($"~Time to calculate (ms): {eachStart.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comparing the solutions, please mention compatibility. Which of those solutions will work on non-win platforms?

Comment: ManagementObject code using "\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem=@" doesn't work on Windows XP because apparently Win32_OperatingSystem is not a singleton on XP. Instead I found that I needed to use a query to find the primary instance and loop over the query results, as demonstrated in this answer which worked for me on both XP and Win 7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7407346/382885

Comment: Great answer. Thanks ! I just wanted to add two things : GetTickCount64() is not supported on versions of Windows before Vista, and PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time") takes REALLY long on my W7 laptop (more than one minute. Don't ask why.)

Comment: If you use @"dd\ \d\a\y\s\,\ hh\ \h\o\u\r\s\,\ mm\ \m\i\n\u\t\e\s\,\ ss\ \s\e\c\o\n\d\s", it spaces things out nicely.

"26 days, 05 hours, 32 minutes, 48 seconds"

Answer (score 16):

Precise and bigger than `System.Environment.TickCount`, not involving OS horrific perf counters, WMI or native calls:

```
var ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
var uptime = ((double)ticks) / Stopwatch.Frequency;
var uptimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime);
```

Comment: [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains why this returns the uptime: “QueryPerformanceCounter [...] returns the total number of ticks that have occurred since the Windows operating system was started, including the time when the machine was in a sleep state such as standby, hibernate, or connected standby.”

Comment: @Martin, do I gather correctly from you that `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` then does not include computer sleep time? Please explain.

Comment: I only cited from the article to which I linked, I didn't write it ;-) In that article: “In this context, the term tick refers to a period of time equal to 1 ÷ (the frequency of the performance counter obtained from QueryPerformanceFrequency)”. I’d understand that a tick simply is a unit of time, as is e.g. a “second”, and it seems to me that this is how the word “tick” is used throughout the article. Thus, the computer does not need to run to make “ticks” “occur”, and `GetTimestamp()` _does_ include sleep time. But I do not know the definitive answer to your question.

Comment: This method relies on the system having a HPET so ensure  Stopwatch.IsHighResolution is true before using it. See Remarks section of the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RyanWilliams, so if there is no HPET, what are the alternatives to get hight precision time?

Answer (score 14):

If you are using a later .NET version (Core 3.0/.NET 5.0 or above), then the `Environment` class now has a [TickCount64 property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount64?view=net-5.0).

This doesn't suffer from the wrap-around issues of the `TickCount` property, nor do you have to resort to P/Invoke to get the value.

```
long tickCountMs = Environment.TickCount64;
var uptime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tickCountMs);
```

Comment: Clean solution. Just be careful: By default in Win 11 "uptime" seems to have changed due to fast startup as discussed [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/win-11-shut-down-button-is-not-restting-uptime-get-uptime-is/m-p/3268351/highlight/true#M3083) for example

Comment: This looks like the final answer today - simple, fast, cross-platform

Answer (score 6):

The simplest and proper way to do this is

```
public static TimeSpan GetUptime()
{
    ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject(@"\\.\root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem=@");
    DateTime lastBootUp = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(mo["LastBootUpTime"].ToString());
    return DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - lastBootUp.ToUniversalTime();
}
```

Comment: This returns an exception with the message:`Invalid object path` on Windows 2003 Server running in a web service in IIS6

Comment: This will so amuse you if run on *nix

Comment: and start up time ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple, no but it can be done:

```
    static DateTime getLastBootTime(ManagementObject mObject)
    {
        PropertyData pd = mObject.Properties["LastBootUpTime"];
        string name = pd.Name.ToString();
        DateTime lastBoot = parseCmiDateTime(pd.Value.ToString());
        return lastBoot;
    }

    static ManagementObject getServerOSObject(string serverName)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_OperatingSystem");
        mSearcher.Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", serverName));
        ManagementObjectCollection mObjects = mSearcher.Get();
        if (mObjects.Count != 1) throw new Exception(String.Format("Expected 1 object, returned {0}.", mObjects.Count));
        foreach (ManagementObject m in mObjects)
        {
            //No indexing on collection
            return m;
        }
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
    }
```

Comment: As the question really asks for a simple solution, this is not a correct answer. It is interesting for completeness, though. And won't work outside of windows and even there the compatibility is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

I know question is both old and solved, but the esiest solution I can tink of is just using the Enviroment.TickCount property, which returns the number of millisecounds since the system started:

```
System.DateTime SystemStartTime = DateAndTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
System.DateTime Uptime = DateAndTime.Now - SystemStartTime;
```

This solition is a lot faster than the accepted answare.

Comment: TickCount is returned as an integer but the system timer has more resolution so there is an extended period of time where the tick count is int.MaxValue, and then eventually it goes down to int.MinValue. This method is not useful for servers that are up for months at a time. Technically system timer resolution is also only accurate up to blocks of 10 to 16 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

[edit: ] Completely unnecessary now that .net has `Environment.TickCount64` (or the `Stopwatch` class). Please disregard.

The (one and only) correct answer, [edit: a long time ago in a place far far away: ]

Using the 32-bit timer is incredibly dangerous, and prone to error for all but limited use.

I'm not sure when the NativeMethods class stuff was added to .net, but it was. You definitely want to avoid P/Invoke overhead. Do this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Mu
{

    // prevents PInvoke (not in NativeMethods class) or Stack walk (NativeMethods class) performance penalties.
    internal static partial class SafeNativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        internal extern static UInt64 GetTickCount64();

    }
    public static class MuTime
    {
        public static UInt64 UpTimeMillis {  get { return SafeNativeMethods.GetTickCount64();  } }
    }
}

/*
Dual License (use either, not both). To avoid CC-BY-SA, access a copy of this 
code at (https://pastebin.com/6EKTWsSf) to use under BSD 0-clause license,


Copyright (c) 2020 Robin Davies 
CC-BY-SA 3.0 (due to StackExchange terms of use). Not my fault, blame StackExchange. Fix this 
please, StackExchange!


BSD 0-Clause
Copyright 2020 Robin Davies.

Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED 
WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, 
OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION 
OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF 
THIS SOFTWARE.
  */
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"You definitely want to avoid P/Invoke overhead."_ Using `[DllImport]` _is_ using P/Invoke, surely?

Comment: Methods that don't require marshalling are called directly, *IF* they are included in a class named SafeNativeMethods. A feature that crept into .net somewhere in the 4.x timeframe.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a link for that? The best I could find was [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1060) which states _"SafeNativeMethods - This class suppresses stack walks for unmanaged code permission."_

Comment: Interesting trick, but I'd advise against it. .net is not a windows only framework, right?

Comment: Agreed. Completely superceded by the new Environment.TickCount64, I think. Or the Stopwatch class.