# trying to display the Start date from server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I have an application in C# where I want to show the Start Date from the server... I mean the real date since the server is running....

The goal is to know if the server went down in any moment.

I´m not sure but it has to be any class in C# to be able to get this datetime from the server...

if you execute in the console "net statistics server"... you display exactly the time i mean...

any idea`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you mean by " to get the Start Date from the server" , do you want to know the datetime when server was rebooted ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972105/retrieve-system-uptime-using-c-sharp

Comment: I mean the time when the server start running....

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime start = 
    DateTime.Now - 
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(System.Environment.TickCount);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gareththegeek!