# How to get performance data?

Tags: c#

I want to get the performance data like in the performance tab in the task manager window.

I got this code:

```
using (PerformanceCounter pCounter = new PerformanceCounter())
{               
    pCounter.CategoryName = "Processor"; //this get me the cpu usage
    pCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    pCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

    // will always start at 0
    pCounter.NextValue();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //now matches task manager reading
    float cpuUsage = pCounter.NextValue();

    pCounter.CategoryName = "Memory";
    pCounter.CounterName = "Available MBytes"; //this gets me the available memory
    pCounter.InstanceName = string.Empty;
}
```

I also need:

- The up time (time the server is active HH:mm:ss)
- Number of processes
- Number of threads
- Ethernet usage

I have no idea how to get this data...

Comment: I don't know what is it...

Comment: [Number of processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Number of threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.readonlycollectionbase.count(v=vs.110).aspx)  Ethernet usage is slightly more complicated, found a [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28367/basic-network-utilisation-display) article. [Server up time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/972189/3191303). Sometimes breaking each item down into separate problems will help identify a solution easier than the whole.

Comment: Please add some more tags to your question- windows .net etc.

Comment: AWinkle, thanks for the links. I'll try implementing them.

Comment: AWinkle, thanks for the links.The server up time works well but the other 2 are not quite what I need. I need the total process count and thread count. Do you know where I can find a list of all category names for the PerformanceCounter ? maybe I'll get it from there...

Answer (score 0):

The .net framework provides the System.Diagnostics class with a plethora of methods to access system info including performance data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Diagnostics%28v=vs.90%29.aspx